# python : unzipping error 'no such file or directory'

Tags: python, xpath, zip, unzip

I have zip file downloaded from website. I wanted to make script that rename zip file and before unzip, it checks how many files are in it and unzip it.

The problem is that zip file is in the directory but it keep giving me error that 
'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.zip''
I assumed that It might be caused by file name because I use ubuntu and when I downloaded the file, the name was broken because it was not English. so I changed it into numbers (ex:20176) but still getting this error.

my script
path means absolute path.

```
    data_type = '{}{}'.format('201706', '.zip')
    filename = [i for i in os.listdir('user/directory')]
    filename.sort(key=lambda ctime: ctime[0])
    downloaded = str(filename[0])

    old = os.path.join('user/directory', downloaded)
    new = os.path.join('user/directory', data_type)
    os.rename(old, new)

    zip = ZipFile(data_type)
    archived_files = zip.namelist()
    amount = len(archived_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the first filename in the sorted list is *myfile.txt*. Your code

```
old = os.path.join('user/directory', downloaded)
new = os.path.join('user/directory', data_type)
os.rename(old, new)
```

renames the first file in the directory listing, *user/directory/myfile.txt* (not, due to the considerations above, the oldest one) to *user/directory/201706.zip*. The next statement then tries to open *2010706.zip*, which of course doesn't exist. It should work if you try

```
zip = ZipFile(new)
```

Unfortunately there's no guarantee that the file actually will be a zipfile, so the operation may fail.

Some other points to consider, perhaps in other questions:

I suspect you are misunderstanding the sorting functions: although you appear to want to sort the list of filenames on creation time, just calling a lambda's parameter `ctime` doesn't mean that Python will understand your needs. If only programming languages had a DWIM ("do what I mean") mode, life would be so much easier!

The `key` argument to `sort` is a function that the `sort` function calls once for each value to be sorted, expecting it to return a "sort key" (that is, a value that represents its place in the required ordering). Suppose I take your lambda and apply it to a filename:

```
In [1]: ruth_lambda = lambda ctime: ctime[0]

In [2]: ruth_lambda("MY_FILENAME.TXT")
Out[2]: 'M'
```

You can see that you are sorting on the first character of the filename, and I doubt that's what you really want. But we can go into that later.

A quick note on formatting: it would have been simpler to write

```
data_type = '{}{}'.format(zipfile_name, '.zip')
```

as

```
data_type = '{}.zip'.format(zipfile_name)
```

Finally, since `os.listdir` returns a list, instead of

```
filename = [i for i in os.listdir('user/directory')]
```

it's simpler to write

```
filename = os.listdir('user/directory')
```

though the extra computation will do no harm. As a beginner you will find that as you improve, your older code starts to look really clunky - don't worry about that, it's a common experience! Just move forwards and try not to repeat old mistakes.

Comment: I edited code. Deleted some irrelevant codes and put string instead of 'path'